# how linux ld interprets -lSomething::AnotherSomething (like /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Widgets)

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, ld

I'm getting this error from a CMakeLists.txt:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Widgets
```

I tried doing

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/lib
```

and running make again, but I get the same error. `/home/user/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/lib` has the following files (and more):

```
libQt5Widgets.la
libQt5Widgets.prl
libQt5Widgets.so
libQt5Widgets.so.5
libQt5Widgets.so.5.12
libQt5Widgets.so.5.12.6
libQt5Widgets.so.5.12.6.debug
```

What does ld searches for when you do like this: `-lQt5::Widgets`? I can only imagine it searching for  `libQt5Widgets.x`

**UPDATE:**

```
project(QuanergyClient)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#  This should match what's in include/quanergy/client/version.h
set(QUANERGY_CLIENT_VERSION "3.3.2")

#required to prevent macro definition of min and max in windows
add_definitions(-DNOMINMAX)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

option(NoViz "Do not build visualizer" OFF)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-format-extra-args -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-conversion")
endif()

# Offer the user the choice of overriding the installation directories
set(INSTALL_LIB_DIR lib CACHE PATH "Installation directory for libraries")
set(INSTALL_BIN_DIR bin CACHE PATH "Installation directory for executables")
set(INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR include CACHE PATH "Installation directory for header files")
set(INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR share/${PROJECT_NAME} CACHE PATH "Installation directory for CMake files")

option(PACKAGE_FOR_DEV "Create -dev package" ON)
option(BUILD_APPS "Build applications" OFF)


# Make relative paths absolute (needed later on)
foreach(p LIB BIN INCLUDE CMAKE)
  set(var INSTALL_${p}_DIR)
  if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE "${${var}}")
    set(${var} "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${${var}}")
  endif()
endforeach()


SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}")
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
LIST(FIND CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" is_system_dir)
IF("${is_system_dir}" STREQUAL "-1")
  SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}")
ENDIF("${is_system_dir}" STREQUAL "-1")



find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system thread REQUIRED)

if (NoViz OR CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
  find_package(PCL REQUIRED common io)
else()
  find_package(PCL REQUIRED common io visualization)
endif()

file(GLOB_RECURSE project_HEADERS
    "*.h"
    "*.hpp"
)
#message(STATUS "LIBS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
#message(STATUS "PCL LIBRARIES: ${PCL_LIBRARIES}")

include_directories(
  include
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(
  ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR}
  ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})


set(client_SRCS
  src/modules/polar_to_cart_converter.cpp
  src/modules/distance_filter.cpp
  src/modules/ring_intensity_filter.cpp
  src/modules/encoder_angle_calibration.cpp
  src/common/point_xyz.cpp
  src/common/point_xyzir.cpp
  src/parsers/data_packet_parser_00.cpp
  src/parsers/data_packet_parser_01.cpp
  src/parsers/data_packet_parser_04.cpp
  src/parsers/data_packet_parser_m8.cpp
  ${project_HEADERS}
)


add_library(quanergy_client SHARED ${client_SRCS})

if(WIN32)
  target_link_libraries(quanergy_client ws2_32 ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()

configure_file(doxyfile.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doxyfile" @ONLY)

#############
## Testing ##
#############

# Unit Tests
find_package(GTest)

if (GTEST_FOUND)
  add_executable(test_quanergy_client test/test_encoder_angle_calibration.cpp)

  target_link_libraries(test_quanergy_client
    quanergy_client
    ${GTEST_LIBRARIES}
    boost_system
    )

  add_test(encoder_calibration_unit_test test_quanergy_client)
endif()

find_package(Doxygen)
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  add_custom_target(doc "${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE}" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doxyfile")
endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)


#  This is the export CMake stuff form.

if (PACKAGE_FOR_DEV)

  install(DIRECTORY include/quanergy
    DESTINATION "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}" COMPONENT dev)

  if(WIN32)
  install(TARGETS quanergy_client
    EXPORT QuanergyClientTargets
    RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" COMPONENT shlib)
  else()
  install(TARGETS quanergy_client
    EXPORT QuanergyClientTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" COMPONENT shlib)
  endif()

else()

  set_target_properties(quanergy_client 
    PROPERTIES SOVERSION ${QUANERGY_CLIENT_VERSION})

  if(WIN32)
  install(TARGETS quanergy_client
    EXPORT QuanergyClientTargets
    RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" COMPONENT shlib NAMELINK_SKIP)
  else()
  install(TARGETS quanergy_client
    EXPORT QuanergyClientTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" COMPONENT shlib NAMELINK_SKIP)
  endif()

endif()


# Add all targets to the build-tree export set
export(TARGETS quanergy_client FILE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/QuanergyClientTargets.cmake")

# Export the package for use from the build-tree
# (this registers the build-tree with a global CMake-registry)

# Which of these is correct? The latter follows the pattern set by
# quanergy_core.

# export(PACKAGE QuanergyClient)
export(PACKAGE quanergy_client)

# Create the QuanergyClientConfig.cmake and QuanergyClientConfigVersion files
file(RELATIVE_PATH REL_INCLUDE_DIR "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}" ${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR})


# ... for the build tree
set(CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
configure_file(cmake/QuanergyClientConfig.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/QuanergyClientConfig.cmake" @ONLY)

# ... for the install tree
set(CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS "\${QUANERGY_CLIENT_CMAKE_DIR}/${REL_INCLUDE_DIR}" "${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
configure_file(cmake/QuanergyClientConfig.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/QuanergyClientConfig.cmake" @ONLY)

# ... for both
configure_file(cmake/QuanergyClientConfigVersion.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/QuanergyClientConfigVersion.cmake" @ONLY)

if (PACKAGE_FOR_DEV)
  # Install the QuanergyClientConfig.cmake and QuanergyClientConfigVersion.cmake

  message("config: ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/QuanergyClientConfig.cmake")

  install(FILES
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/QuanergyClientConfig.cmake"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/QuanergyClientConfigVersion.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}" COMPONENT dev)

  install(EXPORT QuanergyClientTargets DESTINATION "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}" COMPONENT dev)

endif()

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
if(PACKAGE_FOR_DEV)
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "quanergy-client-${QUANERGY_CLIENT_VERSION}-dev")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME "quanergy-client-dev")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "Quanergy client library - development")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SECTION libdevel)
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libpcl-common-1.7-dev (>= 1.7.0), libpcl-io-1.7-dev (>= 1.7.0), libboost-dev (>= 1.54), libboost-system1.54.0, quanergy-client")
  configure_file(debian/postinst-dev.in "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/postinst")
  configure_file(debian/preinst-dev.in "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/preinst")
  configure_file(debian/postrm-dev.in "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/postrm")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/preinst;${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/postinst;${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/postrm;")
else()
  set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "quanergy-client-${QUANERGY_CLIENT_VERSION}")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME "quanergy-client")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "Quanergy client library - runtime")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SECTION libs)
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "quanergy-client (>= 0.1.0), libpcl-common-1.7 (>= 1.7.0), libpcl-io-1.7 (>= 1.7.0), libboost-system1.54.0")
  configure_file(debian/postinst.in "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/postinst")
  configure_file(debian/prerm.in "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/prerm")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/postinst;${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/prerm;")
endif()
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "Quanergy Systems Inc.") #required
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_VERSION ${QUANERGY_CLIENT_VERSION})
if ("x86_64-linux-gnu" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}")
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "amd64")
else()
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "i386")
endif()
include(CPack)

##########
#  apps  #
##########

if (PCL_VISUALIZATION_FOUND)
  add_executable(visualizer apps/visualizer.cpp apps/visualizer_module.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(visualizer quanergy_client ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()

add_executable(dynamic_connection apps/dynamic_connection.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dynamic_connection quanergy_client ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

message("PCL_LIBRARIES: ${PCL_LIBRARIES}")
message("Boost_LIBRARIES: ${PCL_LIBRARIES}")
```

Here's the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Widgets
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/dynamic_connection.dir/build.make:345: recipe for target 'dynamic_connection' failed
make[2]: *** [dynamic_connection] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/QubesIncoming/social/quanergy_client-master'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/dynamic_connection.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dynamic_connection.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/QubesIncoming/social/quanergy_client-master'
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can't find a line where it says anything about Qt5. I even printed out the variables related to the linking of `dynamic_connection` and there is no Qt5 there.

Comment: I'm not sure passing " -lQt5::Widgets" is valid. Can you elaborate on the cmake config that leads to this command being issued?

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica please take a look at my update. I can't find a line where it says anything about Qt

Comment: Maybe the Qt5 dependency is from one of the other packages

Comment: @drescherjm can cmake do that? Do you have any idea on how to find which library requires that? Also, I tried pointing to the folder with Qt5 libraries and it didn't work. I also tried installing qt5-default but it didn't work (shouldn't it?)

Comment: ***can cmake do that?*** Yes. [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/target_link_libraries.html#libraries-for-a-target-and-or-its-dependents](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/target_link_libraries.html#libraries-for-a-target-and-or-its-dependents)

Comment: It may be PCL, its not boost. The dependency may also be in this file: `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/QuanergyClientTargets.cmake`

Answer (score 0):

It puts lib on the front and looks for files ending in `.a` or `.so`. Your command would be looking for `libQt5::Widgets.so` or `libQt5::Widgets.a`. You should use `-lQt5Widgets` instead.

Note that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has no effect on the linker, it is only used when looking for shared libraries at runtime (and shouldn't be necessary then either if using rpath correctly in your executables). You probably want `LIBRARY_PATH` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the folder to look for libraries without altering the CMake file? And this is a project from someone else, I'm not sure why there's `libQt5::Widgets`

Comment: Not that I'm aware of